# How to deploy nodejs, express, socket.io application

Tags: node.js, git, sockets, heroku, express

I have worked on a project and its in my local.
I have used `express` framework with `socket` and other packages.

I'm new to this and not sure what deployment options we have.
I see some options like `AWS`, `Heroku` and etc.

Heroku looks simple.. but at one of the step they are asking to publish to git and clone from there..

I was wondering why do we need to publish to git to deploy it to production.

Currently I have my app in my machine and I run usually by node `app.js`.

I'm not using any data bases. Can any one guide me how do I go about it?

Comment: You should definitely use git. Version control will keep you from making mistakes that could mean the end.. They aren't saying that you should publish it on GitHub or anything (also, you can have private repos on GitHub). They're saying that you have a local git repo and a remote repo hosted by Heroku, which are synchronized when you `git push ...`. When you ran `heroku create` you already made a local git repository and remote git repo `heroku`, both automatically configured. Commit your local changes, and push your master branch to the `heroku` remote repo, and you'll see everything working.

Comment: @lucasem thx for reply.. so we can't deploy with git? if I use git, how do I make it private repo with free of cost?

Comment: well as it is by default, you have one locally (on your computer) and one on heroku (private, automatically configured to be "connected" with your local repo when you `git push heroku master`). If you _did_ want to host your repo privately for free on GitHub (which you totally don't have to), create a new repository on GitHub and you'll see the option.